# How to test entity with @OrderBy annotation is correctly ordered using Spring Boot?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-data-jpa

I have my chat entity which contains a list of messages. These messages should be sorted by creation date, and for this I have it annotated with the orderBy annotation. However, the test is failing, even though this is working correctly in my application, which was failing before I added the annotation.

```
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
class ChatRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    ChatRepository chatRepository;

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;
    
    @Test
    void testMessageOrder() {
        MessageEntity messageEntity1 = MessageEntity.builder().creationDate(ZonedDateTime.now().minusDays(1)).build();
        MessageEntity messageEntity2 = MessageEntity.builder().creationDate(ZonedDateTime.now().minusDays(2)).build();
        MessageEntity messageEntity3 = MessageEntity.builder().creationDate(ZonedDateTime.now().minusDays(3)).build();

        List<MessageEntity> messageEntityList = new ArrayList<>();
        messageEntityList.add(messageEntity2);
        messageEntityList.add(messageEntity1);
        messageEntityList.add(messageEntity3);

        ChatEntity chatEntity = ChatEntity.builder()
                .messageEntityList(messageEntityList)
                .build();

        chatEntity = chatRepository.save(chatEntity);

        ChatEntity chatEntityList = chatRepository.findById(chatEntity.getId()).orElseThrow();

        List<MessageEntity> messages = chatEntityList.getMessageEntityList();
        for (int i = 0; i < messages.size() - 1; i++) {
            assertTrue(messages.get(i).getCreationDate().isBefore(messages.get(i + 1).getCreationDate()));
        }
    }
```

I have also tried this using TestEntityManager:

```
@Test
void testMessageOrder() {
  // Create messages with different creation dates
  MessageEntity messageEntity1 = MessageEntity.builder().creationDate(ZonedDateTime.now().minusDays(1)).build();
  MessageEntity messageEntity2 = MessageEntity.builder().creationDate(ZonedDateTime.now().minusDays(2)).build();
  MessageEntity messageEntity3 = MessageEntity.builder().creationDate(ZonedDateTime.now().minusDays(3)).build();
        
  // Add messages to list in an unordered manner
  List<MessageEntity> messageEntityList = new ArrayList<>();
  messageEntityList.add(messageEntity1);
  messageEntityList.add(messageEntity3);
  messageEntityList.add(messageEntity2);

  // Create chat entity with the list of messages
  ChatEntity chatEntity = ChatEntity.builder()
         .messageEntityList(messageEntityList)
         .build();

  // Save chat entity
  chatEntity = chatRepository.saveAndFlush(chatEntity);
  entityManager.flush();
  entityManager.refresh(chatEntity);

  // Add a new message
  MessageEntity messageEntity4 = MessageEntity.builder().creationDate(ZonedDateTime.now()).build();
  chatEntity.getMessageEntityList().add(messageEntity4);
  chatRepository.save(chatEntity);

  // Retrieve the chat entity
  ChatEntity chatEntityList = chatRepository.findById(chatEntity.getId()).orElseThrow();

  // Retrieve the list of messages
  List<MessageEntity> messages = chatEntityList.getMessageEntityList();

  // Check the order of messages
  for (int i = 0; i < messages.size() - 1; i++) {       assertTrue(messages.get(i).getCreationDate().isBefore(messages.get(i + 1).getCreationDate()));
  }
}
```

But it passes with or without the orderBy annotation.

These are my entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "message")
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MessageEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "content")
    private String content;

    @Column(name = "creation_date")
    private ZonedDateTime creationDate;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "chat_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private ChatEntity chatEntity;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "chat")
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ChatEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "chatEntity", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OrderBy("creationDate")
    private List<MessageEntity> messageEntityList;
}
```

Thank you very much.